# Crossing number of the Grötzsch graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

Related wikipage: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6tzsch_graph

Is the crossing number of the Grötzsch graph known? I have heard it conjectured to be 5 (certainly it is no greater), but came up empty-handed in my search of the literature.

Comment: For what it's worth (as crossing numbers are notoriously hard to compute), I think it is still open. I also added the graph theory tag. 

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The crossing number of the Grötzsch graph is 5.

Crossing numbers are believed to be difficult to compute in general.  (The corresponding decision problem is NP-hard.)  However, for small graphs and small crossing numbers, it is possible to find an optimal planar drawing.  For example, see Markus Chimani's thesis ["Computing Crossing Numbers"](http://www.ae.uni-jena.de/alenmedia/dokumente/ComputingCrossingNumbers_PhDthesis_Chimani_pdf.pdf) for more information.

The Open Graph Drawing Framework (OGDF) can [compute crossing numbers](http://www.ogdf.net/doku.php/tech%3ahowto%3aplz).  After compiling the program on the linked page and entering the Grötzsch graph, my computer computed that the optimal planar drawing has 5 crossings.  Let me emphasize that this technique is *exact*, not heuristic.

Comment: Nice! I see OGDF has been updated as well (2022/02). I have not known what is the code function of OGDF to calculate the crossing number.